# Sending data from Hono to Ditto

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot

Eclipse Hono and Eclipse Ditto have been connected successfully. And when I try to send the data from the Hono I will get 202 Accepted response as shown below.

```
(base) vignesh@nb907:~$ curl -X POST -i -u sensor9200@tenantSensorAdaptersss:mylittle -H 'Content- 
Type: application/json' -d '{"temp": 23.07, "hum": 45.85122}'  http://localhost:8080/telemetry
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
content-length: 0
```

But when I checked for the digital twin value using localhost:8080/api/2/testing.ditto:9200 - It is not getting updated.

I came across the error while enquiring the logs.

```
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 15:18:26,273 INFO  [ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:TelemetrySenderImpl-7] 
o.e.d.s.c.m.a.AmqpPublisherActor akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/sharding/connection/27/Amma123465/pa/$a/c1/amqpPublisherActor2 - Response dropped, 
missing replyTo address: UnmodifiableExternalMessage [headers={content- 
type=application/vnd.eclipse.ditto+json, orig_adapter=hono-http, orig_address=/telemetry, 
device_id=9200, correlation-id=ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:TelemetrySenderImpl-7}, response=true, error=true, 
authorizationContext=null, topicPath=ImmutableTopicPath [namespace=unknown, id=unknown, group=things, 
channel=twin, criterion=errors, action=null, subject=null, path=unknown/unknown/things/twin/errors], 
enforcement=null, headerMapping=null, sourceAddress=null, payloadType=TEXT, textPayload= 
{"topic":"unknown/unknown/things/twin/errors","headers":{"content- 
type":"application/vnd.eclipse.ditto+json","orig_adapter":"hono- 
http","orig_address":"/telemetry","device_id":"9200","correlation- 
id":"ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:TelemetrySenderImpl-7"},"path":"/","value": 
{"status":400,"error":"json.field.missing","message":"JSON did not include required </path> 
field!","description":"Check if all required JSON fields were set."},"status":400}, bytePayload=null']
gateway_1        | 2019-10-14 15:19:47,927 WARN  [b9774050-48ae-45c4-a937-68a70f8defe5] 
o.e.d.s.g.s.a.d.DummyAuthenticationProvider  - Dummy authentication has been applied for the following 
subjects: nginx:ditto
gateway_1        | 2019-10-14 15:19:47,949 INFO  [b9774050-48ae-45c4-a937-68a70f8defe5] 
o.e.d.s.m.c.a.ConciergeForwarderActor akka://ditto-cluster/user/gatewayRoot/conciergeForwarder - 
Sending signal with ID <testing.ditto:9200> and type <things.commands:retrieveThing> to concierge- 
shard-region
gateway_1        | 2019-10-14 15:19:48,044 INFO  [b9774050-48ae-45c4-a937-68a70f8defe5] 
o.e.d.s.g.e.HttpRequestActor akka://ditto-cluster/user/$C - DittoRuntimeException 
<things:precondition.notmodified>: <The comparison of precondition header 'if-none-match' for the 
requested Thing resource evaluated to false. Expected: '"rev:1"' not to match actual: '"rev:1"'.>.
```

I have set the all the json fields. But not sure what I am missing.

I also can see this in the log

```
nginx_1          | 172.18.0.1 - ditto [14/Oct/2019:13:19:48 +0000] "GET 
/api/2/things/testing.ditto:9200 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Eclipse Hono to Ditto - "description":"Check if all required JSON fields were set."},"status":400}" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941682/connecting-eclipse-hono-to-ditto-descriptioncheck-if-all-required-json-fie)

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the message in Ditto protocol or applied payload transformation?
Looks like a duplicate of [Connecting Eclipse Hono to Ditto - "description":"Check if all required JSON fields were set."},"status":400}" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941682/connecting-eclipse-hono-to-ditto-descriptioncheck-if-all-required-json-fie?rq=1) where you had the same problem and error before.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did send the message in Ditto Protocol.

Comment: The error message saying `JSON did not include required </path> field!` indicates that the required "path" field in the Ditto Protocol message was missing.
From your cURL I only see that you send `-d '{"temp": 23.07, "hum": 45.85122}'` - which is not a Ditto Protocol message.